# What is the weight read by a scale on top of an Atwood's machine?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Let's say between the ceiling and the massless, frictionless pulley is a scale. If you let go of the weights, right before they start falling, you measure the weight. I thought that because if the weights were simply in free-fall the scale would read nothing, but because the weight's acceleration is impeded by the tension force, it would read T, or 2mMg/(m+M) (I think this was the tension force for masses m and M on an Atwood machine). But I've seen another answer from a reputable source that claims that the scale would read 2T, which makes plausible sense since both of the masses together are impeded by two separate, although the same, tension forces.

Which one is it? 2T or T, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case where the masses are equal and not moving, that is, the whole system is static and in a force equilibrium. Then each mass will be subject to a force $mg$ exerted by the earth and a tension force $T$ exerted by the rope. Since we have an equilibrium, we know that $T=mg$.

Now consider the whole system of the two masses, the massless rope and pulley. It feels the total force $2mg$ exerted by the earth and the normal force $F$ exerted by the underlying surface. As the system as a whole is in an equilibrium as well, we have $F=2mg = 2T$.

This stays true, when the system is not in an equilibrium any more. You can think of it like this: The pulley only has direct contact to the rope, so it's the rope's tension which pulls the pulley down, not the masses hanging on the rope.